# Mobile finger slide over to increase / decrease rating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm building a simple rating page. It has 5 stars. Right now what it does is, if you tap on a star, it highlights the star and the ones before it, and clears the ones after it. Easy.

Here's the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/XSBYvlFm4l   - although not really sure if you can look at it on mobile....

How do you do it so that when the user tamps his finger down on the phone and moves it back and forth and the stars move accordingly?

Also I'm doing this all using Javascript, lot of for loops.... seems inefficient? (I don't know if it is, just seems so to me). Would welcome any better suggestions.

Thanks!!